# html and combining span ID's into one span ID

Tags: html, css

I'm working on an eBook which requires me to create an overlay. All is working fine except in some cases I have a drop cap combined with the rest of the word which need to be highlighted at the same time.
The code below is my current problem. I need to have the two span ID's combined into on without destroying the html.
Any ideas?

```
<p class="ParaOverride-1"><span id="_idTextSpan017" class="DropCap-color CharOverride-6" style="position:absolute;top:-109.78px;left:26.39px;">W</span><span id="_idTextSpan018" class="PageText-v1 CharOverride-7" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:1626.19px;letter-spacing:-2.6px;">hat </span>
```

Comment: I tried the nested span with no luck. the SMIL is not highlighting the first letter even with the nesting...any other ideas? Here is what I have currently:<p class="ParaOverride-1"><span id="pg3dropcap"><span id="_idTextSpan017" class="DropCap-color CharOverride-6" style="position:absolute;top:-109.78px;left:26.39px;">W</span><span id="_idTextSpan018" class="PageText-v1 CharOverride-7" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:1626.19px;letter-spacing:-2.6px;">hat </span></span>

Answer (score 0):

You need a nested `<span>`:

```
<span id="myID">
     <span id="x">

     </span>
     <span id="y">

     </span>
</span>
```

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion.

Comment: @cendrick nested `<span>` should work. you have some issues with your styling. see https://jsfiddle.net/5m0mafsr/1/

Comment: It's strange. The first word...'What' is not being highlighted at all once I nested the two span ID's. I wonder if SMIL does not allow for nested span ID's in its markup.

Comment: I am sorry to ask this again, but the one idea above was not working and I'm trying to solve this for my client. Here is the code I have: <p class="ParaOverride-1"><span id="_idtest">
     <span id="_idTextSpan017" class="DropCap-color CharOverride-6" style="position:absolute;top:-109.78px;left:26.39px;">W</span>
     <span id="_idTextSpan018" class="PageText-v1 CharOverride-7" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:1626.19px;letter-spacing:-2.6px;">hat</span></span>